# Styling CSS Unordered Lists

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to style an unordered list so that the second line and the ones after that are indented the same as the first line of the list item?

Please see the example for exactly what I mean

```
O----First Line
     --SECOND LINE SHOULD START HERE
     --EVERY OTHER LINE SHOULD BE LIKE THIS ALSO
```

Comment: You can nest a `ul` inside of another `ul` to get what you want.

Comment: When you mention those indented lines past the first, are those sub-bullets or are they wrapped lines of text?

Comment: W3 wiki - [Nested lists in HTML](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists#Nesting_lists)

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement my comment, here is a jsfiddle demonstrating what I mentioned. http://jsfiddle.net/R5ptL/

```
<ul>
   <li>Parent</li>
   <ul>
       <li>Child1</li>
       <li>Child2</li>
       <li>Child3</li>
   </ul>
   <li>Parent2</li>
</ul>
```

And if you want them to be the same style...

```
ul, li {
    list-style-type: circle; /* or whatever style you choose */
}
```

EDIT: How to do this with multiple unordered lists AND CSS only: http://jsfiddle.net/R5ptL/1/

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. He specifically wanted the multiple lines within a single list item to have indentation on every line after the first one.

Comment: @Jason - That is one way to interpret the question. Semantically, a nested list like this would be more suitable if the first item is a parent of the subsequent items.

Comment: @Jason The OP did not state he only wanted there to be one list. Is looks like he is building a heirarchy and this is the correct way to do so.

Comment: @gwin003 - The parent closing `</li>` should wrap around its child `<ul>`

Comment: @misterManSam I agree that it would make more sense, but it's possible that the OP has long blocks of text in his unordered lists that he wants to format in a special way. We would need clarification on this to provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: @misterManSam Hm, I've never done it that way. Checking with my fiddle, it actually produces the same result both ways.

Comment: @gwin003 - [Here is the doc on nested lists](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists#Nesting_lists). I recall problems with it a decade ago on IE6? `"The key to nesting lists is to remember that the nested list should relate to one specific list item. To reflect that in the code, the nested list is contained inside that list item."`

Answer (score 0):

use the css first-child selector to apply the indent to every line other than the first.
ex:

```
ul li:first-child{margin:0px;}
ul li{margin:5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li:not(first-child) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

or

```
li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Couple things: There's no explanation here as to why this would work, it's just code. Second, while it would work, it's dependent on knowing the exact width that the indent is. It would probably be better to embed a second level of `ul` `li` to move the sub items over automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's like this: (HTML solution, not CSS)

```
<ul>
<li> first item </li>
<li> second item
<ul>
<li>first item of second list</li>
<li>second</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li> continue primary list </li>
</ul>
```

In short, you nest a complete new UL inside the primary UL.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was apparently incorrect after further testing. This should work though:

```
ul li {
    text-indent:-10px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

NOTE: This answer runs under the assumption that every line other than the first is simply wrapped text. If those other lines are meant to be sub-points, go with gwin003's answer.